# Subclass UITableView with Custom UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

**What I have**: 10+ view controllers using a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`. Each view controllers load different data and forward to different sub-pages, thus they cannot combine together.

The aim of the change is to centralize the management of table view's look & feel in a single custom `UITableView` subclass. But since the data loaded by each view controller is different, I think the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` have to be assigned to its original view controller class.

How do I make the change? Or I am thinking at wrong direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tableview's datasource can be separate and independent from its delegate. So, put all of your appearance configurations in a UITableView subclass that implements its own delegate methods, and then create a separate NSObject subclass for each tableview that is responsible for the datasource implementation.

Comment: Do you mean UITableView subclass or a UITableViewController subclass?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a superclass for all your view controllers that collects all the common logic.

Comment: though this answer does not directly answers my question, it does inspire me of changing my code structure. Thanks.